# How to save screenshots with time stamp programatically in iPhone?

Tags: ios, datetime, screenshot

Hi I am developing an iPad app that application  needs to take screenshots automatically and images should be saved in the name of screen name long with the current date and current time which is in the device. Someone help me to do this.

I have tried the following code.In that code Screenshot is taken and i will print the name in label in that view. But in the label time is not accurate so i would like to save the image in the name of screen name appended by time.

```
        //-- Screen Capture --------------------------------------------------------------------//

UIImage *image = nil;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(loginBgImgVw.frame.size);

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:MM:SS"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

NSString *dateToday = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 600, 44)];
[label setText:dateToday];
NSString *fileNameStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_Login_%@",providerIdStr,dateToday];

[label setText:fileNameStr];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[loginBgImgVw addSubview:label];
[formatter release];


[loginBgImgVw.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];     
image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();        
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();        

//=--

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docspath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"path=--%@",paths);

NSString *dataPath = [docspath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ProviderID_%@",providerIdStr]];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
}

NSString *savedImagePath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Login_Provider.png"];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.2);
[imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,self,@selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:),NULL);

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
```

Comment: We need more information than this. What have you tried? By 'taking a screen shot', do you refer to pressing the home & lock buttons at the same time, or using a button within the app?

Comment: am using button to do this action. On clicking the submit button screenshot should capture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your date formatter as,

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
```

`MM` is for representing month and `mm` for minutes.